# How do I create a bottom navigation view that looks like this? Is it possible?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

The UX designer just gave me this, however, I have no idea on how to create a bottom navigation view layout that looks like this.
[I want to add in the center a circular button which is separated from the main bottom navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhOKZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes its possible
use this

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
>


<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
    app:menu="@menu/yourMenu"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/mediumBlue"
    app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp"
    app:fabCradleMargin="8dp"
    app:hideOnScroll="true"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="20dp">

</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/skyBlue"

    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
    app:maxImageSize="35dp" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

"yourMenu "should look something like that

```
  <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
    android:title="@string/Home"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
    android:title="@string/Search"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me from days of research!

Answer (score 1):

If you want this?

[image: you want like this?]

then follow this instruction.

add dependencies

```
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Add these codes in your activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icons_adduser"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <com.codeplayon.custombottobar.CustomBottomNavigationView1
        android:id="@+id/customBottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Create a java file  Custom Bottom NaviBar with the name CustomBottomNavigationView1.java

```
public class CustomBottomNavigationView1 extends BottomNavigationView {

    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;

    /** the CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS represent the radius of the fab button */
    private final int CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 128 / 2;
    // the coordinates of the first curve
    private Point mFirstCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();

    //the coordinates of the second curve
    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    private Point mSecondCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();
    private int mNavigationBarWidth;
    private int mNavigationBarHeight;

    public CustomBottomNavigationView1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomBottomNavigationView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomBottomNavigationView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorAccent));
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        // get width and height of navigation bar
        // Navigation bar bounds (width & height)
        mNavigationBarWidth = getWidth();
        mNavigationBarHeight = getHeight();
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the start point before curve
        mFirstCurveStartPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the end point after curve
        mFirstCurveEndPoint.set(mNavigationBarWidth / 2, CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4));
        // same thing for the second curve
        mSecondCurveStartPoint = mFirstCurveEndPoint;
        mSecondCurveEndPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);

        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 1st control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4), mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 2nd control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mSecondCurveControlPoint1.set(mSecondCurveStartPoint.x + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mSecondCurveStartPoint.y);
        mSecondCurveControlPoint2.set(mSecondCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4)), mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x, mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mFirstCurveEndPoint.x, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mSecondCurveControlPoint1.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mSecondCurveControlPoint2.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mSecondCurveEndPoint.x, mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.lineTo(0, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Create a menu file with bottom_menu and add this code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icons_adduser"
            android:title="Page1"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:title="Page2"
            android:icon="@drawable/icons_editprofile"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_music"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/iconsgear"
            android:title="Page3"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_schedules1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="Page4"
        android:icon="@drawable/icons_editprofile"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

add this to MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CustomBottomNavigationView1 customBottomNavigationView1 = findViewById(R.id.customBottomBar);
        customBottomNavigationView1.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_menu);
    }
}
```